# Windows: OpenCV is installed but getting "Unable to import cv2" error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

I realise there are a lot of similar questions on SO, and I have been browsing them but haven't found any success in their solutions so far.

I'm using:

- Anaconda 1.9.12
- Python 3.8.3
- Windows 10

I installed opencv by doing:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

When I do

```
conda list
```

I can see the following:

```
opencv                    4.0.1            py38h2a7c758_0
opencv-python             4.3.0.36                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python-headless    4.3.0.36                 pypi_0    pypi
```

And also

```
py-opencv                 4.0.1            py38he44ac1e_0
```

So it would seem that opencv is installed. However, when I'm writing python code and I have:

```
import cv2
```

I get the "Unable to import cv2" error.

This may have something to do with how Anaconda manages installations and environments, but I had thought everything was installed under my custom environment, since that's where I've been doing everything.

Note: I've also tried other commands such as

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Which look like they succeed, but then I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Why use pip to install these packages? Also, you should try all this in a new Conda environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have three different distributions of Open CV installed. This is probably what's causing the conflict here. There is a post on [pyimagesearch - pip install opencv](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/) which outlines the differences between the different pip packages you can install for Open CV. opencv-python and opencv-python-headless are similar, but opencv-python is used for a system with a GUI, and headless for a system without.

I have replicated these steps on a Windows machine using Anaconda and can confirm Open CV installed and ran successfully.

[image: Open CV Windows Versions]:

Steps I followed:

- Open Anaconda Prompt
- If using a venv, enter `conda activate myenv`
- Still in Anaconda prompt, run `pip install opencv-python`
- When you use `conda list` you should see a single open cv present.

In your case, I would try to remove opencv-python-headless and opencv, if you want to use opencv-python. To remove using pip, use the command:

```
pip uninstall package name
```

Otherwise it might be worth setting up a new virtual environment in Anaconda and doing a clean install of opencv-python from there.

I used:

- Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12
- Python 3.7.7
- Windows 10

Comment: I've uninstalled opencv-python and opencv-python-headless, but when I tried to uninstall plain old opencv I got the message: "WARNING: Skipping opencv as it is not installed." I had to use "conda uninstall opencv" to remove it. I then did "pip install opencv-python," and "conda list" then showed one installation: "opencv-python." I then went back into VS code (closed and reopened it) but am still getting the error. I'm thinking it might be some kind of path-related issue; maybe I installed/configured something incorrectly. I'll start from scratch and see where I get.

Answer (score 0):

opencv is not compatible with python 3. Try to Install opencv3 in Ananconda.I hope it works.

You can try

`conda install -c menpo opencv=3`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing everything on the base conda environment instead of my custom one (e.g. conda install opencv), and it started working. I guess something wasn't configured correctly in my custom environment, or it lacked the ability to do something (due to permissions?).